Definition of a local minimum of a function over a closed set
On an open set $D$, a local minimum $x$ is well-defined, we need to find an open ball with radius > 0 around $x$ on which the function is greater or equal than the function at $x$.
But on a closed set $D'$, this definition with an open ball doesn't work since we would "get out" of $D'$ by considering an open ball with radius >0 in the cases where $x$ is a boundary point. Therefore, can we say that a point $x$ minimises a function on a closed set? Surely we can, since in 1 dimension $x=0$ minimises the function $f(x) = x$ if we consider the closed set [0, 1]. But I'm missing the formalism in which the definition of a local minimum makes sense for closed sets.

I'm not sure the first statement is true. Specifically, if you consider the open set to be $\mathbb{R}$ then for example the function $f(x) = x$ doesn't have a well-defined minimum.
Actually you have at least one point of minimum if the function is continuous and the domain is compact given by Weierstrass thereom. If your domain is the reals then this translates to the domain being closed and bounded.

@rescon I don't understand what you mean, the function $f(x) = x$ doesn't have a minimum on $\mathbb{R}$, I agree, but that's consistent with the fact that if there was one minimum $x_0$ we would need to find an an open ball with radius > 0 around $x_0$  on which the function is greater or equal than the function at $x_0$

The notion of local minimum is defined for general topological spaces, all what you need is the notion of a neighborhood.

But what is the neighborhood of a point on the boundary of a closed set?

You should read about the subspace topology.

Unfortunately I don't have the mathematical background to understand anything they say. In particular, they don't define U in their definition and I'm not familiar with the notion of topological space.

Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ where $(V,m)$ is a metric space. Then, $\bar{x} \in S$ is called a local minimum of $f$ over $S$ if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$f(\bar{x})\le f(x), \,  \forall x\in S \cap \{x\in V: m(x,\bar{x})< \epsilon\},$$
where the local neighbourhood is considered as the intersection of an open ball and $S$.
For $V=\mathbb R^n$, it is given by
$$f(\bar{x})\le f(x), \,  \forall x\in S \cap \{x\in \mathbb R^n: \|x-\bar{x}\|_2< \epsilon\}. $$
For example, for function $f(x)=-x^2$ over closed interval $[-\frac12,1]$, both points $-\frac12$ and $1$ are local minima, where note that the point $1$ is the global minimizer. The function $f(x)=-x^2$ over the interval $[-\frac12,1)$, only has a local minimum at the point $-\frac12$, and has no global minimizer.
